# Prettyprint XML

Tags: xml, jsf, richfaces, pretty-print

We have some XML stored as a blob in a MySQL database, and display it in a rich faces modal panel as raw text via a servlet. We'd like to use google prettyprinting (or another if anyone thinks there's something better) but I'm not sure how to achieve this. Here is my JSF from the modal panel

```
<rich:panel>
  <s:fragment>
    <object data="#{xmlEntity.xmlUrl}" 
            type="application/xml"/>
  </s:fragment>
</rich:panel>
```

Any help would be much appreciated
Many thanks
Ian

Answer (score 0):

From the prettify docs, you just need to do following:

```
<pre class="prettyprint">
 #{yourBean.yourXmlData}
</pre>
```

And don't forget to include the `run_prettify.js` file.
If that does not work as expected, try to use:

```
<pre class="prettyprint">
 <h:outputText value="#{yourBean.yourXmlData}" escape="false"/>
</pre>
```

I don't have a test environment to test which one should work, but I think one of them would solve the issue.
I hope this helps